# Remove keyboard when table cell selected

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, uitextfield, resignfirstresponder

I have a modal set up like this:

[image]

Despite appearances, the first two fields are UITextFields that become first responders and display the keyboard. The third 'Department' item is a table view and pushes another view.

I have implemented a scroll view so that while either of the fields is being edited, the user can scroll around and reach the department cell:

[image]

When it is selected, before the push, I would like to hide the keyboard.  It's a small detail, but try adding a new event on Apple's 'Calendar' app.  It opens with the first text field as first responder (so keyboard is present).  If you select the start/end cell, the keyboard hides as the next view is pushed.

How do I achieve this?  As a test I tried:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSLog(@"hiding keyboard");
if ([ingredientName isFirstResponder]) {
    NSLog(@"resigning name field");
    [ingredientName resignFirstResponder];
}
else if ([ingredientAmount isFirstResponder]){
    NSLog(@"resigning amount field");
    [ingredientAmount resignFirstResponder];
}
```

}

The logging confirms that these are getting called.  But the keyboard does not hide.  It simply stays in place as the view slides out.  And on return, the previous field still has focus (and the keyboard is out).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:
Are you using a segue for pushing that other VC?  If so, resign the keyboard in the prepareForSegue method.

If not, try using willSelectRowForIndexPath instead of didSelectRowAtIndexPath

Comment: I am using a segue, and inserting the code in prepareForSegue did the trick.  Sometimes it's easy to miss the obvious - Thank you!

Comment: No problem, I miss the obvious on a daily basis :)

Answer (score 1):

`resignFrstResponder` will not dismiss the keyboard when you're using a modal view.

Another dev found a workaround for this behavior here: http://viraj-workstuff.blogspot.com/2010/12/resignfirstresponder-does-not-hide.html

Comment: This might be out of date.  I can successfully resign first responder on other actions in the modal (e.g. hitting the 'return' key) by hooking it up to the same code.

Comment: resignFirstResponder does work in a modal view.  The issue here is that didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called AFTER prepareForSegue.

Comment: It did not for me so I'm very grateful for the link

Answer (score 1):

Not terribly elegant, but try stealing the firstresponder status with an ad-hoc, invisible `UITextField`:

```
-(void)dismissKeyboard {
    UITextField *textField;
    textField=[[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    [self.view addSubview:textField];
    [textField becomeFirstResponder];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [textField removeFromSuperview];
    // [textField release] // uncomment if not using ARC
}
```